# Horizontal DIV with children elements to be scrolled to by Id

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, navigatetourl

I have an ASP.NET Core Razor Page where is a collection of elements scroll-able horizontally on touch or on nav button click.

I am not js specialist and I need one more functionality:
On button click, I need to "JUMP" to element that has given ID.

How can I achieve that on horizontal scroll div?

Answer (score 0):

This answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11986374/1684254)  can help. 
This is a quote from that answer

call this when you need to scroll the screen to an element which has id="yourSpecificElementId"

```
window.scroll(0,findPos(document.getElementById("yourSpecificElementId")));
```